# Problems launching debugger in new Admin instance of VS 2022 via Debugger.Launch()

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2022

Recently, I've been having strange issues when I want to debug a sub-process of my service project that is running in an Admin instance of Visual Studio 2022.

First, a few words about my setup:

1. one instance of a regular non-Admin VS 2022 that is running my client project
2. a second elevated instance of VS 2022 that is running my Windows Service project in normal command-line mode (i.e. not as an actual service, but as an elevated normal app, because it needs the elevated privileges to do its work).

Depending on the client request, the service app can spawn simple child worker processes. These workers are also under my control and I have the source code.

Occasionally, I need to debug one of these worker processes, when I discover that they don't behave as expected. I'm aware I can simply run and debug them directly, which I often end up doing. But sometimes it's also useful to observe the entire chain (i.e. the client, the service and the worker process) all at once, each running in their own VS instance, stopped at their respective breakpoints. This is where a strategically placed `Debugger.Launch()` command inside the worker code really shines. Or at least, it does when the damn thing works!

Now onto the problem...

When the worker's `Debugger.Launch()` line is hit, I'm first presented with a dialog that asks me if I want to launch a JIT debugger. This is expected:

[image: JIT debugger window]

When I choose "Yes, debug MyWorkerProcess.exe", I'm presented with an option to start a new elevated VS instance, which I confirm. And this is where most of the time, I run into inexplicable problems (it **maybe** works correctly 1 out of 5 times). If it happens that I'm inside the unfortunate 80%, then when the VS starts, I'm immediately greeted by the following dialog:

[image: VS error]

It doesn't matter how I answer it, there's always another such dialog coming. Sometimes even two of them at the same time, one over another. If I'm really patient and close every one of them, then eventually, after 10+ such dialogs, the VS finally loads. But instead of displaying my worker process solution, it opens the source code (i.e. the `.cs` file) that called the `Debugger.Launch()` in a Notepad window! And of course there's no chance of debugging anything in there, so all I can do is close it.

If I try this whole process a couple more times, I can eventually get it to work as I initially expected. But it's driving me absolutely bonkers!

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** Not that I have any hopes, but in case anyone is wondering what the `ActivityLog.xml` says... It's an enormous stack trace of the error, basically. It doesn't reveal anything I can find useful. All I can surmise is that it's probably some kind of a race condition going on, where a VS internal service is required before it is available.

Here is the excerpt for interested:

> SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Parallel.Extension.ExtensionPackage]Source: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0' Description: The SVsRegisterEditors service is unavailable.
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceUnavailableException: The SVsRegisterEditors service is unavailable. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceUnavailableException: The SVsLegacyRegisterEditors service is unavailable.
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceExtensions.<GetServiceAsync>d__3`2.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Packages.ShellService.ShellServicePackage.<<InitializeAsync>g__CreateServiceAsync|1_0>d.MoveNext()

... and so on for miles...

Comment: What happens if you run all your Visual Studio instances as administrator? The first thing I used to do on a fresh Windows install is make it so VS always launches as administrator. I'd also highly suggest not using `Debugger.Launch()` and instead [attach to the running process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022) from VS directly